# Create attribute from another attribute with a method

Tags: python, oop, methods, attributes

I have a folder with .txt files and I want to create a list of objects where each object has 3 attributes(file, name, text). 'name' is just the name of the file without the '.txt' extension. 'text is the content of the file'

I'm stuck, and this is what I have done so far.

```
class My_class():
   def __init__(self, file):
       self.file = file
       self.name = file.split('.')[0]

   def get_text(self):
       folder_file = folder + '\\' + self.file
       with open(folder_file, 'r') as f:
           text = f.read()
       return text

folder = r'<the folder path that contains the .txt files>'

list_of_files = [file for file in os.listdir(folder) if file.find('.txt') != -1]

objects = [My_class(f) for f in list_of_files]
[print(obj.file) for obj in objects]
[print(obj.name) for obj in objects]
```

I want  to create a method called get_text, and execute it during the code, so it creates a new attribute for each object called text.

Once the method has been called I want to be able to execute the following command and print out the content of the files.

```
[print(obj.text) for obj in objects]
```

Comment: Why not just do `self.text = text` before returning it in `get_text`?

Comment: Are you using Python 3.8?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7. I have an external function that can do what I want without creating a class and objects, but I'm trying to learn some OPP and I want the function to be a method of the class, because it is only used for the attributes within the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your `get_text` method set the object's attribute:

```
def get_text(self):
    folder_file = f"{folder}\\{self.file}"
    with open(folder_file, 'r') as f:
        self.text = f.read()
```

In this case, there would be no need for a `return` value. If you choose to do this, then it's often good practice to define the `text` attribute in your `__init__` method and set it equal to `None`. This makes it easier to see what attributes your object uses when you come back to it later (and you've forgotten what you did), and it also makes it simple to perform a check for retrieval, as in the case where you only want to collect objects for which you've retrieved the text:

```
[obj.text for obj in objects if obj.text is not None]
```

Alternatively, you could define `self.text` in your `__init__` method by setting it equal to the method call `self.get_text()`. This would mean that text is automatically retrieved when the object is initialized. In this case, you should keep the `get_text` definition the way it is--i.e., have it create a local variable `text` and then return that variable. Here's what that would look like:

```
class My_class():
   def __init__(self, file):
       self.file = file
       self.name = file.split('.')[0]
       self.text = self.get_text()
```